# Importing a library in one file and using it in another file, without importing

Tags: python, import, libraries, normalization

There is a file named **transforms.py**, in it `torchvision.transforms` is imported and some custom transformations are defined. In another file named **main.py**, **transforms.py** is imported.

Now, in order to use `torchvision.transforms.Normalize` in **main.py** without importing it, Will it work (`Normalize` is not used in **transforms.py**, only imported)? And if it works, what's the reason behind it?

**transforms.py**:

```
from torchvision.transforms import *
...
Custom transformations defined
...
```

**main.py**

```
from data import transforms 
...
normalize = transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.5,0.5,0.5],std=[0.1,0.1,0.1])
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that should work. Reason being that `import` adds whatever you're importing to the namespace of the current file, which is exactly the same as what happens when you `def`ine a function, in that

```py
from module import a_function
```

and

```py
def a_function:
```

both end up with `a_function` defined. Either way, you can then `import` that file and access `a_function` with `that_file_name.a_function()`

Comment: So, is it the same for libraries, as well? Whichever libraries are imported in a file can be used in another file without importing?

Comment: @Nephophile yep, if you import a library to a script you get everything in that library into the script's namespace. When you import that script somewhere else, you get everything in its namespace into the current one - including the library